# Simplification and Partial Fractions

Tags: calculus, integration

I was recently studying partial fractions when I came across 
$$\frac{1}{(x+1)(x-1)^2}$$ .
Playfully, I tried to solve it as follows: $$\frac{1}{(x+1)(x-1)(x-1)}= \frac{1}{(x^2-1)(x-1)} = \frac{Ax+B}{x^2-1} + \frac {C}{x-1}$$.
This resulted in an unsolvable system of equations. I wondered if it's because I didn't factorise a reducible denominator, but then I tried to decompose a fraction with a denominator of $(x^2-9)(x-2)$ and it worked without having to factorise the first bracket. I used the scientific method (which I don't like to use in maths) and deduced that the break down is due to nothing other than the denominator being in the form $$(x^2-a^2)(x-a)$$ where a is a constant. Rather, it should be in the form $$(x+a)(x-a)^2$$.

**My question is, why? What exactly goes wrong when I don't simplify a reducible polynomial?**

Another question which is, in a sense, related to the first is that in another example i came across $$\int \frac{x+3}{(x-2)(x-1)} dx$$
Of course, this decomposes into $$\int \frac{5}{3(x-2)}-\frac{2}{3(x+1)} dx$$.
The textbook integrates this as $$\frac 53 \ln(x-2) - \frac 23 \ln(x+1) + c$$.
I, however, didn't take the $\frac 53$ and $\frac 23$ as constants to be taken out. What I did was as follows: $$\int \frac{5}{3x-6} - \frac{2}{3x+3}dx = \frac 53 \ln(3x-6) - \frac 23 \ln(3x+3)$$
I integrated the denominators and treated the 3 as a coefficient of $x$, yet there is an extra $ln 3$ in my solution. 
**Again, what goes wrong when I don't simplify polynomials?**

Comment: For the second question: Nothing, as additive constants do not matter.

Comment: In the second question you already noted $+C$ then why were you confused? XD $log 3$ is a constant isn't it, and can be pulled out.

Comment: @Aminopterin oh yeaa, i forgot the +c in my solution.lol i was so frustrated that i substituted numbers for x, forgetting that an integral has two limits. But now i tried both solutions with two limits and they're the same. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given are all linear polynomials (i.e. $x-a$ for $a \in \mathbb{R}$) $p,q$, we want that $$
\frac{r_1}{p^2} +\frac{r_2}{q} =\frac{1}{p^2q}.
$$ Can real polynomials $r_1,r_2$ always be found? Yes! Indeed, if arranged, the identity (except on $x=$ roots of $p$ and $q$) becomes $$
r_1 q +r_2 p^2 =1.
$$ This is possible if and only if $$
\mathrm{gcd}(q,p^2) =1
$$ and this is true, so Euclidean algorithm may be applied.

However, for $$
\frac{s_1}{p} +\frac{s_2}{pq} =\frac{1}{p^2q}.
$$ Then $s_1,s_2$ do not exist in general. In fact, doing the same, we have $$
s_1 pq +s_2 p =1.
$$ But $$
\mathrm{gcd}(pq,p) =p \neq 1.
$$ And the B\'ezout identity can never hold.

Answer (score 0):

Note that any fraction 
$$ \frac{p(x)}{(x-1)^2(x+1)} $$
where $p$ is a polynomial of degree at most two, can be written in the form 
$$ \frac{a}{(x-1)^2} + \frac{b}{x-1} + \frac c{x+1}$$
(as partial fraction decomposition is always possible). If you now replace the $\frac{a}{(x-1)^2}$ by $\frac{\alpha x+\beta}{x^2-1}$, you drop some terms. Note that 
$$ \frac{\alpha x +\beta}{x^2 - 1}= \frac 12\frac{(\alpha - \beta)}{x+1} + \frac 12\frac{\alpha + \beta}{x-1} $$
Hence, the term $\frac a{(x-1)^2}$ cannot be represented in the form $\frac{\alpha x + \beta}{x^2 - 1}$. In the case, where $a \ne 0$, you just cannot solve the equation you get, think for example of 
$$ \frac{x+1}{(x-1)^2(x+1)} \ne \frac{\alpha x + \beta}{x^2 - 1} + \frac\gamma{x-1} $$
for all $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$.